# Need an XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, tree

Hi I have a tree like xml structure... I want to transform it using XSLT to calculate productPrices...if it was a linear structure I could have used a simple sum function witha a filter on name...But as its a tree like structure it needs some kind of recursive transformation...Can somebody suggest me some technique or an approach to do this tranformation...I am trying to write it from my end...It would be helpfull if you can suggest some approaches...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <Name>X2</Name>
        <Price>1</Price>
        <Product>
            <Name>X1</Name>
            <Price>1</Price>
            <Product>
                <Name>X1</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
            </Product>
            <Product>
                <Name>X2</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
            </Product>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name>X2</Name>
            <Price>1</Price>
            <Product>
                <Name>X1</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
            </Product>
            <Product>
                <Name>X1</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
                <Product>
                    <Name>X2</Name>
                    <Price>1</Price>
                </Product>
            </Product>
        </Product>
    </Product>
    <Description>
        <text>dsd</text>
    </Description>
    <Description>
        <text>dsd</text>
    </Description>
</Products>
```

The final structure that I need it to be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <Name>X2</Name>
        <Price>1</Price>
        <!--Total Price of X2 Products-->
        <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
        <Product>
            <Name>X1</Name>
            <Price>1</Price>
            <!--Total Price of X1 Products-->
            <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
            <Product>
                <Name>X1</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
                <!--Total Price of X1 Products-->
                <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
            </Product>
            <Product>
                <Name>X2</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
                <!--Total Price of X2 Products-->
                <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
            </Product>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name>X2</Name>
            <Price>1</Price>
            <!--Total Price of X2 Products-->
            <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
            <Product>
                <Name>X1</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
                <!--Total Price of X1 Products-->
                <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
            </Product>
            <Product>
                <Name>X1</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
                <!--Total Price of X1 Products-->
                <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
                <Product>
                    <Name>X2</Name>
                    <Price>1</Price>
                    <!--Total Price of X2 Products-->
                    <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
                </Product>
            </Product>
        </Product>
    </Product>
    <Description>
        <text>dsd</text>
    </Description>
    <Description>
        <text>dsd</text>
    </Description>
</Products>
```

Comment: @bejoy: May I suggest a little restructuring? You can move `Name` and `Price` as attributes for a `Product` element. Makes the nesting readable as well as easily iterable.

Comment: @conqenator: thanks for your comment but Its not feasible to modify the structre...

Comment: @bejoy: So What do you want to know? There's no question in your "Demand" above. According to the faq I'm forced to be nice but let me say this is not a place where you throw your stuff and get your work done by others. I you have concrete problems with transformation of your documents feel free to post your problems and be sure to get a good answer.

Comment: Hey Chris...I have an average knowledge on XSLT transformations. I could have used the sum function with a filter if this xml was in a linear structure. by using the tag <xsl:value-of select="sum(node()[Name = 'X1']Price)"/>  but as this is a hieararchy structure I am not able to do it... I dont want you to write the Complete XSLT...Just give me options I will do the rest...

Comment: Exactly! The "tone" is why most people don't bother answering questions like these. You need to come across as polite for somebody to lend time for your question. (Well unless, they have a lot of time on their hands to simply work for reputation points.)

Comment: Sure...Thanks chris and Conqenator..I have rephrased the question...

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a complete solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vProd1TotalPrice"
     select="sum(//Product[Name='X1']/Price)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vProd2TotalPrice"
     select="sum(//Product[Name='X2']/Price)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Product">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::Product)]"/>
   <TotalPrice>
     <xsl:value-of select=
      "$vProd1TotalPrice *(Name='X1')
      +
       $vProd2TotalPrice *(Name='X2')
      "/>
   </TotalPrice>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Product"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <Name>X2</Name>
        <Price>1</Price>
        <Product>
            <Name>X1</Name>
            <Price>1</Price>
            <Product>
                <Name>X1</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
            </Product>
            <Product>
                <Name>X2</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
            </Product>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name>X2</Name>
            <Price>1</Price>
            <Product>
                <Name>X1</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
            </Product>
            <Product>
                <Name>X1</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
                <Product>
                    <Name>X2</Name>
                    <Price>1</Price>
                </Product>
            </Product>
        </Product>
    </Product>
    <Description>
        <text>dsd</text>
    </Description>
    <Description>
        <text>dsd</text>
    </Description>
</Products>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Products>
   <Product>
      <Name>X2</Name>
      <Price>1</Price>
      <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
      <Product>
         <Name>X1</Name>
         <Price>1</Price>
         <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
         <Product>
            <Name>X1</Name>
            <Price>1</Price>
            <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
         </Product>
         <Product>
            <Name>X2</Name>
            <Price>1</Price>
            <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
         </Product>
      </Product>
      <Product>
         <Name>X2</Name>
         <Price>1</Price>
         <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
         <Product>
            <Name>X1</Name>
            <Price>1</Price>
            <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
         </Product>
         <Product>
            <Name>X1</Name>
            <Price>1</Price>
            <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
            <Product>
               <Name>X2</Name>
               <Price>1</Price>
               <TotalPrice>4</TotalPrice>
            </Product>
         </Product>
      </Product>
   </Product>
   <Description>
      <text>dsd</text>
   </Description>
   <Description>
      <text>dsd</text>
   </Description>
</Products>
```

**Explanation**:

It is straight-forward to specify the required sum of `Price` elements in a single XPath expression as done in the code when defining the two global variables.

No recursion is necessary.

Comment: Excellant Dimitre...Thanks a lot...I modified it a little bit to make it generic...You are a saviour...Thanks again...

Comment: @bejoy: As noted by @Flack: At SO the official ettiquette is to accept the best answer (this is done by clicking on the green checkmark next to the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, to give you direction..

You could start off by writing a template for a `Product` element.

Use the `xsl:for-each` and recursively apply the same template. (check out recursive templates)

And as you suggested, you will need to use `xsl:variables` smartly alongwith the `sum()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Again Dimitre...I modified the xslt to make it a little generic...now it looks like this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-16" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Product">
    <xsl:variable name="ProductLine" select="."/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::Product)]"/>
            <TotalPrice>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(//Product[Name=$ProductLine/Name]/Price)"/>
            </TotalPrice>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Product"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So if I give a modified xml as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <Name>X2</Name>
        <Price>1</Price>
        <Product>
            <Name>X1</Name>
            <Price>1</Price>
            <Product>
                <Name>X1</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
            </Product>
            <Product>
                <Name>X3</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
            </Product>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name>X2</Name>
            <Price>1</Price>
            <Product>
                <Name>X3</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
            </Product>
            <Product>
                <Name>X1</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
                <Product>
                    <Name>X2</Name>
                    <Price>1</Price>
                </Product>
            </Product>
        </Product>
    </Product>
    <Description>
        <text>dsd</text>
    </Description>
    <Description>
        <text>dsd</text>
    </Description>
</Products>
```

It still gives me the output as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <Name>X2</Name>
        <Price>1</Price>
        <TotalPrice>3</TotalPrice>
        <Product>
            <Name>X1</Name>
            <Price>1</Price>
            <TotalPrice>3</TotalPrice>
            <Product>
                <Name>X1</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
                <TotalPrice>3</TotalPrice>
            </Product>
            <Product>
                <Name>X3</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
                <TotalPrice>2</TotalPrice>
            </Product>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name>X2</Name>
            <Price>1</Price>
            <TotalPrice>3</TotalPrice>
            <Product>
                <Name>X3</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
                <TotalPrice>2</TotalPrice>
            </Product>
            <Product>
                <Name>X1</Name>
                <Price>1</Price>
                <TotalPrice>3</TotalPrice>
                <Product>
                    <Name>X2</Name>
                    <Price>1</Price>
                    <TotalPrice>3</TotalPrice>
                </Product>
            </Product>
        </Product>
    </Product>
    <Description>
        <text>dsd</text>
    </Description>
    <Description>
        <text>dsd</text>
    </Description>
</Products>
```

Stackoverflow and the experts here are awesome...Thanks again!

Comment: Because `$ProductLine/Name` is contextless, you could just declare `$ProductName` as `Name` instead of `$ProductLine` as `.`